# How to display date and string when using @NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following `@NamedQuery` in my *`Entity`*:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
```

I am using the above in `DAOImpl` class as

```
TypedQuery<Customer> q =  entityManager.createNamedQuery(
    "Customer.findAll", Customer.class);
```

When I am displaying date fields in application, all date values are displayed as

`2013-07-14 00:00:00.0, 2013-07-28 00:00:00.0` etc  and String fields are displayed as

```
test.entity.Employee@750d24b2
```

How can I format date and display string data as stored in database?

**Edit 1**

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Employee #" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{req.empNumber}" />
</p:column>
```

and in Entity `empNumber` as

it is declared as

```
private Employee empNumber;
```

Comment: Post an example of how you display the strings, I understand the dates but the Strings are very odd.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Because of mapping I have declared as `private Employee empNumber;` is that causing the problem?

Comment: Yes thats not a string its a class.  Did you annotate with `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` to create the association?

Comment: An Employee is an Employee. It's not a String. So when you display it, its `toString()` method is called.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes I did annotate as `@ManyToOne` and from `Employees` `@OneToMany`

Comment: @Polppan Thats good from there its just changing the Expression Language to access that field.  Make sure you have proper bean accessors setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your receiving `test.entity.Employee@750d24b2` your not accessing a `String` on the JSF, instead your accessing a class via JSF EL.

You should access a field on the `Employee` class like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{req.employee.empNumber}" />
```

This assumes that the `req` attribute contains get/set methods for `employee` and `employee` contains get/set methods for `empNumber`.  With these accessors in place JSF EL should display the value of the `empNumber`.

For displaying the date, I would recommend using JSF tags.

```
<h:outputText value="#{req.someDate}" >
              <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
 </h:outputText>
```

[Documentation](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html)

Comment: Kevin I have `private Employee empNumber;` in managedbean and in Employee class I have getter and setter for employeeNo, however when I run my application I am getting `#{req.employee.employeeNo}": The class 'test.net.entity.Customer' does not have the property 'employee'.`

Comment: You need a `public Employee getEmployee()` method in Customer. That's what "property" means. Kevin told it in his answer: *"This assumes that the req attribute contains get/set methods for employee"*.

Comment: Is `req` of type `Customer`? If so `Customer` must have an `Employee` field (requires Association to be established, think `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, etc).  The `Customer` class must also have get/set methods for `Employee`

Comment: @JBNizet I know this one isn't rocket science, but the more my comments align with yours, the more I feel like I'm developing into a better programmer.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Thanks a lot for your valuable comments, it was my bad, i got confused with employee and empNumber. Appreciated.

Comment: @Polppan Any time. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a date as a formatted string in JSF has nothing to do with @NamedQuery or however you choose to fetch that date from database. Anyways, to show formatted date,

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

replace with actual value and desired pattern.

As for the Employee, when you use an Object (instead of a String) as the value of a h:outputText, the toString() method of the object is invoked. That is why you see what you see. you should be using a property of the employee, like #{req.employee.empNumber}